# in Tibco 6.x DB connection failed, requires restart of appnode

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-topic, tibco-designer

I have a problem with tibco Administrator TEA.  My Tibco project is using a database connection with mysql server , and I have deployed it on TEA , when the Database Server is Down I see in Tibco logs DB Connection failed and when the database server is again up I am still seeing in Tibco logs DB Connection is failed ,  to solve that i need to restart the AppNode but I don't want to restart it every time . Is there any way to avoid that and let my application work automatically when the DB Server is up again . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

doesn't restart of application work? Do as follows:
* create moduleActivator process and include DBConnection call there and load all configuration within it to be used within process
* in the same bwp, catch exception event and do shutdown procedure, which will shut down your application.

Once DB connection is up, just start up your engine again and it should work without any exceptions.

Check and let me know if it works. If it doesn't, please share logs.